# Ubuntu custom Live CD autostart graphical application

Tags: live-cd, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

I'm trying to build a customized Ubuntu Live CD which should automatically run a graphical application on startup. It should behave like the standard Ubuntu Live CD, which loads the graphical environment and then shows the first screen where it asks you if you want to run Ubuntu or install it.

I managed to create a customized version of the Live CD which also holds my application, but I can't figure out at what point (in what script) during startup I should launch my application, and how to disable the screen shown by Ubuntu. Basically it should assume that I want to always run Ubuntu (never install it), and go directly to my graphical application.

I looked at the scripts from the Ubuntu Live CD, but I can't figure out where I need to change them. Any pointers are welcome.

Also, in general, any pointer is welcome towards documentation about the steps performed by the Ubuntu Live CD during startup. For example where in the process is the Ubiquity installer launched?

Comment: What are you using to create customized installer?